# Ruby: yield block from a block?

Tags: ruby, lambda

Is it possible for a `lambda`, `proc`, `method` or other type of block in ruby, to yield to another block?
something like...

```
a = lambda {
  puts 'in a'
  yield if block_given?
}

a.call { puts "in a's block" }
```

this doesn't work... it just produces

```
in a
=> nil
```

Is there way to get the block to call a block?

Comment: This is still not possible in Ruby 2.7... does anyone know, if Ruby 3 will support such a syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can you can do that, but something similar would be:

In Ruby 1.8.6:

```
a = lambda { |my_proc|
  puts 'in a'
  my_proc.call
}

a.call(lambda { puts "in a's block" })
```

In Ruby 1.9.1, you can have block parameters

```
a = lambda { |&block|
  puts 'in a'
  block.call
}

a.call { puts "in a's block" }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call the block, which is similar to yielding.

```
a = lambda {|&block| block.call if block}
a.call {print "hello"}
```

Note that

```
a.call
```

Will not return an error.

Comment: Not that it's a big deal, but I noticed that you were the first to answer.