# How to pass a block to another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, block

Assuming I have the following proc:

```
a = Proc.new do
    puts "start"
    yield
    puts "end"
end
```

Also assuming I pass `a` to another method which subsequently calls `instance_eval` on another class with that block, how can I now pass a block onto the end of that method which gets yielded in `a`.

For example:

```
def do_something(a,&b)
    AnotherClass.instance_eval(&a) # how can I pass b to a here?
end

a = Proc.new do
    puts "start"
    yield
    puts "end"
end

do_something(a) do
    puts "this block is b!"
end
```

Output should of course should be:

```
start
this block is b!
end
```

How can I pass the secondary block to a in the `instance_eval`?

I need something like this for the basis of a Ruby templating system I'm working on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble yielding inside a block/lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982630/trouble-yielding-inside-a-block-lambda)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use yield in `a`. Rather, you have to pass a `Proc` object. This would be the new code:

```
def do_something(a,&b)
    AnotherClass.instance_exec(b, &a)
end

a = Proc.new do |b|
    puts "start"
    b.call
    puts "end"
end

do_something(a) do
    puts "this block is b!"
end
```

`yield` is only for methods. In this new code, I used `instance_exec` (new in Ruby 1.9) which allows you to pass parameters to the block. Because of that, we can pass the Proc object `b` as a parameter to `a`, which can call it with `Proc#call()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=Proc.new do |b|
    puts "start"
    b.call
    puts "end"
end
def do_something(a,&b)
  AnotherClass.instance_eval { a.call(b) }
end
```

Comment: That wont work. `instance_eval` doesn't capture variables in the same way as normal blocks do.