# How can I pass a block to an `instance_eval`-ed block?

Tags: ruby, block

I want to pass a block to a block that is `instance_eval`-ed like this,

```
instance_eval(&block) { puts "test" }
```

where `block` is defined as containing something like:

```
puts "Incoming message:"
yield
```

Is this possible? I discovered a way of doing this with fibers, but I'm trying to use `yield` first. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314893/341772), it looks like this might not be possible, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to what you're trying to do? It's not really clear. Also your example is passing two blocks to `instance_eval`, which makes no sense.

Comment: You want that `yield` to yield to your `{ puts "test" }` block?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make sense in that it's not actually valid, but I want the second block to be passed to the block that instance_eval is actually evaluating, so the final output would be "Incoming message:\ntest".  I'm looking for something that works similarly but _is_ valid, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's weird, indeed. Why `instance_eval` ? It's usually used to change self, and evaluate in the context of the receiver.

```
cat = String.new('weird cat')

block1 = lambda do |obj, block|
    puts "Incoming message for #{obj}:"
    block.call
end

block2 = Proc.new { puts "test" }

block3 = lambda {|obj| block1.call(obj, block2)}

cat.instance_eval(&block3)
```

Execution (Ruby 1.9.2) :

```
$ ruby -w t2.rb 
Incoming message for weird cat:
test
```