# Extending a class method in a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm playing with ruby's metaprogramming features, and I'm finding it a bit hairy. I'm trying to wrap a method call using a module. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
module Bar
  module ClassMethods
    def wrap(method)
      class_eval do
        old_method = "wrapped_#{method}".to_sym
        unless respond_to? old_method
          alias_method old_method, method

          define_method method do |*args|
            send old_method, *args
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def bar(arg = 'foo')
    puts arg
  end

  wrap :bar
end
```

Three questions:

1. Is there any way to do this without renaming the method, so as to allow the use of `super`? Or something cleaner/shorter?
2. Is there a clean way to set the default values?
3. Is there a means to move the `wrap :bar` call further up?

Comment: In real life I would use class inheritance for that.

Comment: Me too, but I'm trying to make sense of this all. :-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631182/difference-between-class-eval-and-instance-eval-in-a-module

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613323/yielding-in-an-anonymous-block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Cleaner/shorter

```
module ClassMethods
  def wrap(method)
    old = "_#{method}".to_sym
    alias_method old, method
    define_method method do |*args|
      send(old, *args)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend ClassMethods

  def bar(arg = 'foo')
    puts arg
  end

  wrap :bar
end
```

As far as I know there is no way to achieve this without renaming. You could try to call `super` inside the `define_method` block. But first of all, a call to `super` from within a `define_method` will only succeed if you specify arguments explicitly, otherwise you receive an error. But even if you call e.g. `super(*args)`, `self` in that context would be an instance of Foo. So a call to `bar` would go to the super classes of `Foo`, not be found and ultimately result in an error.

2) Yes, like so

```
define_method method do |def_val='foo', *rest|
  send(old, def_val, *rest)
end
```

However, in Ruby 1.8 it is [not possible](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/using-define_method-with-blocks-in-ruby-18/) to use a block in `define_method`, but this has been fixed for 1.9. If you are using 1.9, you could also use this

```
define_method method do |def_val='foo', *rest, &block|
  send(old, def_val, *rest, &block)
end
```

3) No, unfortunately. `alias_method` requires the existence of the methods that it takes as input. As Ruby methods come into existence as they are parsed, the `wrap` call must be placed after the definition of `bar` otherwise `alias_method` would raise an exception.